# foreign key data deletion should display error for primary key

Tags: sql-server

i have two tables Table1 and Table2. Where table1 column primary key is referred to table2 column as foreign key.

Now i have to display a error message of constraint violation when ever i delete records from table2 which is having foreign key column of table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right your column A (say) in table 1 references column B (say) in table 2.
What you can do is set the `ON DELETE` to `NO ACTION` which will prevent deletion of records from table 2 if any children of it still exists in table 1.

You can can do this by:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD FOREIGN KEY (A) REFERENCES TABLE2 (B) ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a constraint violation if you delete records from the child table and not the parent. It is normal to delete child records. For instance if I have a user table and a photos tables that contains the userid from the users table, why would I want to stop that action and throw an error if I want to delete a photo? Deleting a child record doesn't also delete the parent.

If you really want to do that, then you must do it through a trigger (make sure to handle multiple record deletes) or if the FK is a required field, then simply don't grant permissions to delete to the table. Be aware that this may mean you can never delete any records even when you try to delete. A simple method may be to not have a delete function available in the application.

I suspect what you really need to a to get a better definition of what is needed in the requirements document. In over 30 years of dealing with hundreds of databases, I have never seen anyone need this functionality.